# Create relationship with properties using a query in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I would like to know if this is possible. I have a query that produces a nice report showing a relationship between two entities through two other nodes. There can be more than one path. I now want to create a direct relationship between those two nodes and count the number of paths and sum based upon data in the nodes in between. the report query is below.

```
match (bo:BuyerAgency)<-[:IS_FOR_BO]-(sol:Solicitation)-[:SELECTED]->(prop:Proposal)<-[:OWNS_BID]-(so:VendorOrg)
where sol.currStatus='Awarded'
return bo.AgencyName, count(sol.Number) as awards, so.orgName, sum(prop.finalPrice) as awardVolume;
```

What I want to do is similar to below which will not work.

```
match (bo:BuyerAgency)<-[:IS_FOR_BO]-(sol:Solicitation)-[:SELECTED]->(prop:Proposal)<-[:OWNS_BID]-(so:VendorOrg)
where sol.currStatus='Awarded'
create (bo)-[:HAS_AWARDED{awardCount: count(sol.Number), awardVolume: sum(prop.finalPrice)}]->(so);
```

If I remove the properties for the relationship, it works but want to add the properties without to much programing.

I am using the most recent version of Neo4j 3.2.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is you are trying to use `count()` and `sum()` functions in an invalid context. The below query should work:

```
match (bo:BuyerAgency)<-[:IS_FOR_BO]-(sol:Solicitation)-[:SELECTED]->(prop:Proposal)<-[:OWNS_BID]-(so:VendorOrg)
where sol.currStatus='Awarded'
with bo, so, count(sol.Number) as count_sol, sum(prop.finalPrice) as sum_finalPrice
create (bo)-[:HAS_AWARDED{awardCount: count_sol, awardVolume: sum_finalPrice}]->(so);
```

This query uses [WITH](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/with/) to pass `bo`, `so` and the result of the aggregation functions `count(sol.Number)` and `sum(prop.finalPrice)` to the next context. After, these values are used to create the new relation between `bo` and `so`.

Comment: Hi @ArthurJohnson , you are welcome! if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Thanks! :)